# kotlin compiler issues for unresolved class

Tags: maven, kotlin

Kotlin compiler has some confusing error messaging for unresolved classes. One developer's project compiles, and the other developers does not. They have the same code. Here is the error...

```
[ERROR] Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class java.lang.AutoClosable, unresolved supertypes: Object
    class com.mycompany.ProviderObjIdentity, unresolved supertypes: Object
```

I don't know where to start debugging this problem. There are no differences in the code for the projects, but I guess the two developers are using different JDKs. Maybe different versions of maven. Definitely different flavors of linux.

I'd be happy to provide any additional information, I just don't know what would be helpful.

this dev guy's setup is busted:

Kotlin: 1.0.4
sles SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
Linux 3.0.76-0.11-default

mvn -version

```
 Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 06:51:28-0700)
 Maven home: /home/devguy1/apache-maven-3.0.5
 Java version: 1.7.0, vendor: IBM Corporation
 Java home: /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.7.0-ibm-1.7.0/jre
 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
 OS name: "linux", version: "3.0.76-0.11-default", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: How are you running the compiler? From IDE or command line?

Comment: I'm using an IDE and the command line without any issues, and the dev guy's broken setup uses mvn from the command line.

Comment: I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, the only way I was able to fix it was create a brand new project entirely and copy over all my source code.

Comment: @szxnyc maybe upvote if you think this question deserves attention. the downvote was someone's rage against me i think

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Kotlin's issue with IBM J9 JVM implementation reported as [KT-14437](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14437) in the JB issue tracker. The fix is in work and most likely will be included in some upcoming Kotlin release. Meanwhile, you may want to use Oracle JDK as a workaround.